# Replace objects by other objects in-place

Tags: php, proxy-object

Suppose I'd like to build a database abstraction layer, which uses a lazy loading mechanism.

If I ask the layer to load a root object, it loads its external representation and constructs itself.

It then somehow identifies that certain linked objects exist. Since it might be costly to load all up-front, it established proxies for related objects. Such proxies should be able to get passed around.

If a first message is called on such a proxy, it loads its external representation and constructs itself. Since references to the proxy may have been passed around, the created object needs to replace the existing proxy-object in-place.

Can I in-place replace an object with another object in PHP?

Comment: Please give a few example code snippets. Replacing `$this = new obj` is not possible, but it sounds like real `&` references on the related objects might be applicable for once. But generic proxy/interception objects would be an option too, depending on complexity.

Comment: I wonder, that & might not be a solution - since references in PHP aren't references as found e.g. in C. I'll probably add code tomorrow. It's too late today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible for an object to replace all references to itself with another object. Instead, have your proxy objects forward property access and method invocation using [overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). Implement proxying on a base proxy object (named e.g. `OOProxy`), then extend this to a `LazyProxy` class that lazily loads the proxied object. As long as you don't need to examine the type of the object, anything that has a reference to the proxy won't be able to distinguish it from the proxied.

Comment: Thx! Yes, using an the proxy like an adaptor for the real objects would be the standard approach.

Comment: it is possible as long as you always use references and don't use new.  With that said it's a dirty hack and should be avoided in practice...  see : [autoboxing with PHP](http://bit.ly/eSuuzJ)...